# Loading XML from file and parsing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, xml-parsing

I have searched and searched and can't figure out why this code wont load an XML element into the

. I'm trying to load the XML from a file, read for a specific element and put it's data into a specific element.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    type: "GET" ,
    url: "score1.xml" ,
    dataType: "xml" ,
    success: function(xml) {
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML( xml ),
    $xml = $( xmlDoc );
    $home = $xml.find( "home" );
    $( "#home" ).text( $home.text() );
    }       
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body><p id="home"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

`score1.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><score><home>22</home></score>
```

(Should also add that while I've been using PHP/HTML for years, I am a total newbie to OOP and JQuery.)

Comment: Any network or JS errors?

Comment: No JS errors, all running through XAMPP. No console errors.

Comment: Did you try putting a breakpoint inside the `success` callback and inspect the `xml` value?

Comment: @jom Not quite sure how I'd go about that? I have used several console.logs and get null and w.fn.init {}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the `parseXML` line and it works perfectly:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "score1.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {
      var $xml = $(xml);
      $home = $xml.find("home");
      $("#home").text($home.text());
    }
  });
});
```

I've removed this line:

```
var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(xml);
```

And now it works perfectly.

Comment: Good grief that was simple. Thank you! Works perfectly!

Comment: No problem whatsoever! Always glad to help @ChaseCromwell

Comment: Accepted, Stack prevents accepting an answer within 10 min of asking the question.